# API for IIS7 Rewrite Section

Tags: .net, iis-7

Is there an API that I just can't find under system.webserver for the rewrite section, or perhaps under Microsoft.Web.Administration with a strongly typed Rewrite class? I'd rather not have to write that class by hand, since I assume it's already there somewhere for use by IIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the URL Rewrite module is an IIS extension there aren't "strongly typed" classes built into the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace to do this. i.e. there isn't a class called `Microsoft.Web.Administration.UrlRewrite`.

However, you can work with the built-in `ConfigurationSection`, `ConfigurationElementCollection` and `ConfigurationElement` classes to manipulate the `<rewrite>` section of your `web.config`.

One of the IIS Program Managers has a blog entry about programmatically configuring the URL Rewrite Module:

> [Scripting URL rewrite module configuration](http://ruslany.net/2008/07/scripting-url-rewrite-module-configuration/)

That should get you started.

Comment: looks interesting, and gives more solid evidence that I need to weigh the options of using those options or creating a custom class with the objects I need / want.

Comment: @MasterMax, yes unfortunately direct consumption or a wrapper class are your only way forward. Many of the IIS extensions are like this, FTP for example.